# What data type are Java things such as "RESULT_CANCELLED"

Tags: java, android-studio, object-type

When invoking a sub-activity using startActivityForResult(), one uses the setResult() method, its first parameter being either RESULT_OK or RESULT_CANCELLED. I have seen other upper-case 'things' used as well.
What are these 'things'? What data type are they? Is there a list somewhere?
I've tried looking them up in various reference documents, with no success.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Those are variable names.  The convention is to put a name in all caps if it represents a constant value.  That data type could be anything, it depends on the class.  Since they don't have a class prepended, you should check your static imports to figure out what they are.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm still not totally clear. If I changed one of these to CHUCK_BERRY without defining what it was, I'm sure I'd get an error. So these 'Integer constants' must have been defined somewhere. Where and by whom? The answer must be that they are 'System integer constants'. Is THAT an accurate description? And I can't accept that there is no list anywhere. There must be, somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the [`Activity.setResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) method is an `int`.

> Is there a list somewhere?

No, because users can define their own result codes. Quoting the [Activity javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities):

> When an activity exits, it can call setResult(int) to return data back to its parent. It must always supply a result code, which can be the standard results RESULT_CANCELED, RESULT_OK, or any custom values starting at RESULT_FIRST_USER.